# how to get the first priority by applying rules into a data frame in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame including different levels of choices:

```
    df = read.table(text="Index V1  V2  V3  V4  V5
    1   A   A   A   B   A
    2   B   B   B   B   B
    3   B   C   C   B   B
    4   B   B   C   D   E
    5   B   B   C   C   D
    6   A   B   B   B   B
    7   C   C   B   D   D
    8   A   B   C   D   E", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

I would like to create another column to hold the most accepted choice for each row. if there are more than one choices, take the maximum numbers of occurrences. if the maximum number is more than 1, take the first choice with the maximum number of occurrences. So my result is expected:

```
    Index   V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  final
    1   A   A   A   B   A   A
    2   B   B   B   B   B   B
    3   B   C   C   B   B   B
    4   B   B   C   D   E   B
    5   B   B   C   C   D   B
    6   A   B   B   B   B   B
    7   C   C   B   D   D   C
    8   A   B   C   D   E   A
```

Thanks for helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with finding the frequency of values in each row using `table`.  Loop through the rows of dataset except the first column (`apply` with `MARGIN = 1`),  get the frequency with `table`, find the index of the maximum frequency (`which.max`) and get the `names` that corresponds to the max frequency

```
df$final <- apply(df[-1], 1, FUN = function(x) {
          tbl <- table(factor(x, levels = unique(x)))
           names(tbl)[which.max(tbl)]})
df$final
#[1] "A" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "C" "A"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
apply(df[,-1], 1, function(x)
         x[which.max(ave(rep(1, length(x)), x, FUN = sum))] )
#[1] "A" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "C" "A"

df[7,2:6] = c("D", "C", "B", "C", "D")
apply(df[,-1], 1, function(x)
         x[which.max(ave(rep(1, length(x)), x, FUN = sum))] )
#[1] "A" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "D" "A"
```

Comment: if the row 7 change to "D   C   B   C   D", then the result is "A" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "C" "A". The expected is "A" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "D" "A".